# Changing and adding a key-value pair to a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I created a Pizza class and I tried to have a add topping method. I thought you add a key value pair to a dictionary by doing `dictionary_name['keyname'] = value`, so why am I having this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath", line 26, in <module>
    x.add_topping('apple', 0)
  File "filepath", line 21, in add_topping
    self.available_toppings[str(topping)] = self.available_toppings[topping] + amount
KeyError: 'apple'
```

My Pizza class

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = 1
        self.toppings = set()
        self.available_toppings = {}

    def __str__(self):
        top = ''
        for topping in self.available_toppings:
            top += str(topping) + ' '
        if self.toppings == {}:
            top = 'nothing'
        return 'A pizza with a radius of ' + str(self.radius) + ' and covered in ' + top + '.'

    def add_topping(self, topping: str, amount: int):
        if not isinstance(topping, str):
            raise ValueError('Sorry pal, but a topping must be a string')
        if not isinstance(amount, int):
            raise ValueError('Sorry pal, but the amount must be an integer')
        if topping not in self.toppings:
            self.available_toppings[str(topping)] = self.available_toppings[topping] + amount
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

On the r.h.s. `self.available_toppings[topping]` is going to raise `KeyError` if `topping` is not a key in the dictionary; in this case you probably want to assume an amount of zero. So you can use the following instead:

```
self.available_toppings.get(topping, 0)
```

Or even better use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
self.available_toppings = defaultdict(int)
```

and then you can use your code without any further changes.